# Is it possible to create an ALAsset object from NSData or other image type (CFImageRef, CIImage, UIImage)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, nsdata, alasset

Is it possible to create an `ALAsset` object from `NSData` or other image type (`CFImageRef`, `CIImage`, `UIImage`)?

I don't want to save all of my applications images to the camera roll, but I want to be able to upload multiple images to Walgreen's QuickPrints API, which is a compiled library that only takes `ALAssets` for multiple image uploads.

*Edit: My understanding of the Walgreen's API/SDK was incorrect. See my answer for details, if you want multiple images uploaded without using ALAssets, you'll have to upload them one at a time.*

Comment: The question "Is it possible to create an ALAsset [without saving to the camera roll" turns out not to be the question the OP actually wanted an answer to. Note that the OP's own answer to his question has very little to do with the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real answer to this issue is that while Walgreen's documentation wasn't perfectly clear on this at the time of asking, the cart is tracked as  batch with a limit of 100 photos, rather an upload being considered a batch.

As long as you don't send the cart to the Walgreen's API, and receive a checkout URL with:

```
 [checkoutSDK postCart];
```

It will keep track of all single and multiple uploads in a "batch" with a maximum limit of 100, rather than overwriting the previous cart with each call to:

```
 [checkoutSDK upload:someTypeOfImageData];
```

Hopefully they'll add a bit more detail the documentation soon, if they haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs: "An ALAsset object represents a photo or a video managed by the Photo application." So you have no choice but to save the data out if you really need an ALAsset.

Comment: I found a way to work around it in the Walgreens API, but I'm not going to mark this accepted until I'm fully satisfied that there isn't a way to hack around that by constructing a dummy ALAsset. You may be right, but I'm still not entirely convinced it's impossible.

Comment: Then I'll downgrade your question, since you refuse to acknowledge a right answer. Sure there are workarounds, like you can write the same asset over and over with different images, but the fact remains that ALAsset means "file in the photo library" and that's all it means.

Comment: I understand your answer is correct if you're trying to follow best practices and principles, but I already knew that. I read the ALAsset documentation line by line before asking this question. Clearly I was asking about trying to hack something unapproved by Apple together, and book author or not, saying "It's not possible" is an unacceptable answer. This is programming, damn near anything is possible, some things may just be inadvisable.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you asked (and answered) the wrong question. You asked if it's possible to make an ALAsset outside the user's photo library. It isn't. There's no hack that can work around that; this is a sandboxing matter. However, it turns out what you really wanted to know was something about the Walgreen's API.

Comment: If it is impossible to spoof an ALAsset object without saving to the camera roll, prove it to me with more than a single sentence from the documentation, and I'll accept the answer. I could see this being useful in the future, so the question still stands.